# Make error window

Tags: vb.net

I want to create my edition error report form instead default error window.

How I can create my edition form error report?

For example:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to call a custom handler when exception happens? No problem, just define these 3 magic lines in the beginning of your program (as first lines of `Sub Main`):

```
AddHandler Application.ThreadException, AddressOf GenericHandler
Application.SetUnhandledExceptionMode(UnhandledExceptionMode.CatchException)
AddHandler AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException, AddressOf UnhandledHandler
```

Then define GenericHandler and UnhandledHandler, which would call your custom form.

Here is a sample implementation of both handlers:

```
Public Shared Sub GenericHandler(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal args As Threading.ThreadExceptionEventArgs)
  ReportException(args.Exception)
End Sub

Public Shared Sub UnhandledHandler(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal args As UnhandledExceptionEventArgs)
  If Not Debugger.IsAttached Then
    ReportException(args.ExceptionObject)
  End
End If

Public Shared Sub ReportException(ByVal ex As System.Exception)
  MsgBox(ex.ToString, MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly Or MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Unhandled exception - Please contact support")
  'you can further improve this to add custom logging etc.
End Sub
```

Comment: +1 all this while I've been surrounding my code with try catch everywhere!